# Sorting Elements Linked List Insertion Sort in Java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, singly-linked-list, insertion-sort

Hi I am getting Null Pointer Exception from this code in sort method can't figure out why. I would appreciate any response.
Its on **line number 93** in Sort method under the **while** loop **next= first.next**.
Thanks in Advance

```
public class LinkedList {
    Student first,last,match,pointer;
    Course start,end;
    int linkCount = 1;
    public LinkedList(){
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return first==null;
    }
    public void deleteLink(int id){
        Student firstnext = first;
        if(id==first.id){
            Student temp = first.next;
            first = temp;
        }
        else if(last.id==id){
            while(first!=null){
                if(first.next.id == id){
                    first.next=null;
                }
                first = first.next;
            }
            first = firstnext;
        }
        else{
            while(first.next!=null){
                    if(first.next.id == id){
                        first.next = first.next.next;
                    }                
                    first = first.next;
                }
            first = firstnext;
        }

    }    
    public void traverseStudent(){
        Student currentStudent = pointer;       
        while(currentStudent != null) {
            currentStudent.printLink();
            currentStudent.traverseCourse();                    
            currentStudent = currentStudent.next;                    
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }    
    public void insert(String fname, String lname, int id, String courseId, int credits,char grade){
        if(isExist(id)){
           match.insertCourse(courseId,credits,grade); 
        }
        else{
            Student link = new Student(fname, lname, id);
            if(first==null){
                link.next = null;
                first = link; 
                last = link;
            }
            else{
                last.next=link;
                link.next=null;
                last=link;
            }
            linkCount++;
            link.insertCourse(courseId,credits,grade);            
        }        
    }
    public void sort(){
        Student current,next,firstLink = first,temp=null;
        int flag = 0,flag2 =0;
        pointer = null;

        if(first!=null){
            if(first.next==null){
                current = first;
            }
            else{
                while(linkCount>0){                    
                    current = first;
                    next = first.next;

                    while(next!=null){
                        if(current.lName.compareToIgnoreCase(next.lName)>0){
                            current = next;
                            if(flag2 == 0)
                                flag = 1;
                        }                
                        next = next.next;                
                    }
                    first = firstLink;
                    if(flag == 1){
                        deleteLink(current.id);
                        current.next = null;
                        pointer = current;
                        temp = pointer;
                        flag =0;
                        flag2 =1;
                    }
                    else if(flag2 ==1){
                        deleteLink(current.id);
                        current.next = null;
                        pointer.next = current;
                        pointer = pointer.next;
                    }                    
                 linkCount--;                    
                }                
            }
            pointer = temp;
        }
    }

        public boolean isExist(int id){
            Student currentStudent = first;        

            while(currentStudent != null) {
                if(currentStudent.id==id){
                    match = currentStudent;
                    return true;
            }
        currentStudent = currentStudent.next;
        }            
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing with us which line exactly has the NPE.

Comment: Its on line number 93 in Sort method under the while loop "next= first.next".

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you call a method with a null value. The method cannot run as the parameter given has no value.

As you did not provide a specific line of code that is causing the issue, I can only say to check all of the variables that you are using in `sort()` and make sure that they are initialized before you call it.

Comment: I tried everything if you see the code you'll find out I am giving proper checks for null variables.

Comment: Its on line number 93 in Sort method under the while loop "next= first.next".

Answer (score 0):

Selection/Insertion Sort should have two loops (Outer and Inner) => O(n^2).  When the pointer to the current value is greater than the value currently being evaluated - the nodes should be swapped.

Pseudocode:

```
Sort = function(first) {
  var current = first;
  while(current!= null) {
    var innerCurrent = current.next;

       while(innerCurrent != null) {
          if(innerCurrent.Value < current.Value) {
              Swap(current, innerCurrent);
          }
          innerCurrent = innerCurrent.next;
       }

       current = current.next;
  }
}

Swap = function(current, innerCurrent) {

  var temp;
  temp.Value = current.Value;
  temp.Next = current.Next;
  temp.Prev = current.Prev;

  current.Value = innerCurrent.Value;
  current.Next = innerCurrent.Next;
  current.Prev = innerCurrent.Prev;

  innerCurrent.Value = temp.Value;
  innerCurrent.Next = temp.Next;
  innerCurrent.Prev = temp.Prev;

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, Actually I am using two loops you'll see when you read it. and in the way I am deleting nodes so that the outer loop doesn't counts the deleted elements.

Comment: Deleting the node shouldn't "count" it - since after the swap you are going to the next node in the list.  I would think this code could be simplified.  Why are you using the flags in the swap?

Comment: I am using flags to check whether its the first node in pointer variable or next. And sorry I didn't get what you mean by 'Count'.? Could you be more specific